# What does data-structure have to look like for inserting in table

Tags: python, web2py

I have something like this in `my_model.py`

```
table_fields = [
    'my_name-string',
    'my_id-integer',
    ]
```

My goal is to create a table based on this information, so I tried:

```
fields_and_types_dict ={}  
for tf in table_fields:
        fields_and_types = tf.split('-')
        fields_and_types_dict['%s' % fields_and_types[0]] = {}
        fields_and_types_dict['%s' % fields_and_types[0]]['type'] = '%s' % fields_and_types[1]

db.define_table('my_table', fields_and_types_dict)
```

It´s not working properly and I guess I don´t have the right data-structure.
Can anyone provide a hint how it must look like? Thank you in advance.

**Solutions:**

The most elegant solution to use is:

```
db.define_table('my_table', *[Field(*tf.split('-')) for tf in table_fields])
```

as suggested by Anthony.

The not-so-complex solution I used is:

```
tableDef = ['my_table']
for tf in table_fields:
    name, type = tf.split("-")
    tableDef.append(Field(name, type))
db.define_table(*tableDef)
```

as suggested by Vanojx1.

Comment: field_and_type or fields_and_types?

Comment: @AriGold 'fields_and_types', fixed the typos

Comment: After the table name, `.define_table` does not take a dictionary but a set of `Field` objects as positional arguments. So, you would want to create a list of `Field` objects and then pass it using Python's positional argument unpacking syntax (e.g., `db.define_table('my_table', *list_of_field_objects)`).

Comment: Also, as an aside, there is no need for your string formatting code. In Python, `'%s' % some_string` is equivalent to simply using `some_string` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [DOC](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#define_table-signature), try this:

```
tableDef = ['my_table']
for tf in table_fields:
    name, type = tf.split("-")
    tableDef.append(Field(name, type))
db.define_table(*tableDef)
```

Comment: That´s exactly what I was looking for. Thanks alot!

Comment: You can get this down to a simple one-liner: `db.define_table('my_table', *[Field(*tf.split('-')) for tf in table_fields])`